# How to check if a user has already clicked a Button?

Tags: android, boolean, sharedpreferences, android-button, buttonclick

I have a button in my menu with a “promo code” inside. I need to check if a user already clicked it so I can tell him (the next time he clicks it) `“You already redeemed this promo code!”` How do I do that? I need only the piece of code where I can check for button clicked.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    boolean clicked = false;
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.getcode: 
            SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("promo", MODE_PRIVATE);
            boolean activated = pref.getBoolean("activated", false);
            if(activated == false) {  Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getcode);
            AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert  = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            dlgAlert.setMessage(getString(R.string.congrats) + "\n" + getString(R.string.promcd) + "\n" + "ASC2013-"+Build.ID+"-"+android.os.Build.SERIAL.charAt(3)+"-"+Build.SERIAL.charAt(6)+"-"+Build.SERIAL.charAt(9)+"-"+Build.SERIAL.charAt(12));
            dlgAlert.setPositiveButton(R.string.go,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {"lorenzocascio@gmail.com"});
                            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getString(R.string.validreq)+Build.BOOTLOADER);
                            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getString(R.string.why) + "\n" + getString(R.string.validreq1) +"\n"+getString(R.string.dialogMSG1);

                            emailIntent.setType("plain/text");  

                            startActivity(emailIntent);

                        }
                    });
            dlgAlert.setCancelable(true);
            dlgAlert.create().show(); 
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("activated", true);
                editor.commit();
            } 
      break;
    }
      switch (item.getItemId()) {
      case R.id.settings: 
          Intent settings = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Settings.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(settings);


    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save a flag in shared preferences if the user clicks the button. Next time, you can check in the shared preferences if there exists the flag.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("promo", MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean activated = pref.getBoolean("activated", false);
    if(activated == false) {  // User hasn't actived the promocode -> activate it 
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("activated", true);
        editor.commit();
    } 
}
```

Comment: Doesn’t work… :( I can always click the btn.. Even with the new version of your code...

Comment: The code just saves a flag in the shared preferences. If the user hasn't activate the promocode yet, you will run into the if-clause. There you can do something to show the user that he has activated the code, for example show a toast.

Answer (score 5):

How about a simple **boolean flag**?

Set it to false in the beginning - as soon as the user clicks - set it to true.

```
private boolean clicked = false; // this is a member variable

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(clicked) {
                 Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You already clicked!", 1000).show();
            } else {
                 Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You clicked for the first time!", 1000).show();
            }

            clicked = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Please be aware that the "clicked" boolean variable must be a **member variable** of your Activity, otherwise it will **not be visible inside onClick().** A variable being a member variable simply means that it belongs to the class it is in, and not just occurs in a specific method. In the above code, "btn" would be a "normal" variable since it only appears inside onCreate() (a method), whereas "clicked" is declared for the Activity (the class it is in), and is therefore a member variable.

If you want to **save if the user has clicked** even after the app was closed and gets reopened, take a look at the **SharedPreferences**.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

boolean clicked;

clicked = prefs.getBoolean("yourkey", false); // get a value, use whatever key you want

prefs.edit().putBoolean("yourkey", clicked).commit();  // save a value, use same key
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply… can you please share some code? Thanks

Comment: You should also save the boolean somewhere, so the variable is still set to true after a restart of the app.
You may want to do that using the [Shared Preference](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

Comment: Thanks @David… How can i do that?

Comment: @Phil your answer will be accepted in 8 minutes.. sorry but i am a new member! :(

Comment: No problem, please also take a look at my code of the SharedPreferences.

Comment: Initialize the button inside the onCreate() yes. Make "clicked" a member variable.

Comment: How to make clicked a member variable? Sorry! :(

Comment: If a variable is a member variable, it just means that it belongs to the class it is in, and not just occurs in a specific method. see my updated answers code.

Comment: I think you minder stood me… I just compiled the code and what i got is that if the app is just installed, the button works as it should but if it is not clicked the first time i install it, it shows me the else Toast text… :(

Comment: I'm sorry, I dont understand. Please explain further.

Comment: EDIT: I AM TOTALLY STUPID I CHANGED THE POSITION OF ELSE… :)