# How to get the buttons Visibility in Second layout when clicked a button in First layout?

Tags: android

In Android For example,We have four Buttons in first Layout.And we have 10 Buttons in second Layout.
If we clicked on any one Button out of 4 buttons,in next layout any 5 buttons has to Visible and remaining 5 buttons need to Invisible.I did not getting the Logic.Please give me a Snippet.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Layout means, activity?

Comment: You can create this . At first try yourself .

Comment: Search on google Button click to `GONE` another button

Comment: Firtly try  at your end and paste your code here.....

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha Ji well said .

Comment: please tell us, what have you tried?

Comment: Layout means Xml file

Comment: `Please give me a Snippet.` **Why**? This is not how this site works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In first layout class use `SharedPreferences` to store a boolean values which buttons was clicked. In second layout class you would read these values and take some actions.

**To make button invisible (programmatically):**

Set button visibility to [GONE](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/reference/android/view/View.html#GONE) (button will be completely "removed" -- the buttons space will be available for another widgets) or [INVISIBLE](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/reference/android/view/View.html#INVISIBLE) (button will became "transparent" -- its space will not be available for another widgets):

```
View b = findViewById(R.id.button);
b.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

**Using SharedPreferences**

Just read: [How to use SharedPreferences in Android to store, fetch and edit values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values)

**Save any button state**

According to [How to check if a user has already clicked a Button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18303596/how-to-check-if-a-user-has-already-clicked-a-button)

> You can save a flag in shared preferences if the user clicks the
>   button. Next time, you can check in the shared preferences if there
>   exists the flag.
>
> ```
> button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
> @Override
> public void onClick(View v) {
>     SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("promo", MODE_PRIVATE);
>     boolean activated = pref.getBoolean("activated", false);
>     if(activated == false) {  // User hasn't actived the promocode -> activate it 
>         SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
>         editor.putBoolean("activated", true);
>         editor.commit();
>     } 
> }
> ```

If you still have any question, please free to ask

Hope it help